# Props contained an array of objects can not be read in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display a multiple markers in a map.

I have this snippet of code in the parent component :

```
const [coords, setCoords] = useState ([{}])

setCoords(
         [
           {lat: -5.2119899, lng: 119.4461816},
           {lat: -5.209704, lng: 119.44075},
         ]
       )

<ReactGoogleMaps coordinates={coords} />
```

The snippet of code in the child component :

```
const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
<GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={13}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: Number(props.coordinates.lat), lng: Number(props.coordinates.lng) }}
  >
    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: Number(props.coordinates.lat), lng: Number(props.coordinates.lng)}} />}
  </GoogleMap>
));

function ReactGoogleMaps(props) {
    return (
        <div style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}>
            <WrappedMap 
                coordinates={{lat: props.coordinates[0].lat, lng: props.coordinates[0].lng}}
            />
        </div>
    )
};
```

The code above works well. The problem is when the index of coordinates props is changed from 0 to 1, then it returns this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`.

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days. I will really appreciate if anyone can help me with this. Thnak you very much in advance.

Comment: You need to update `coords` with more data  in order to access `coordinates[1].lat`. You are getting the error because there isn't any second element in the `coords` array.

Comment: Your `coordinates` array only has a populated index `0`, nothing at index 1, what other behavior were you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coords is not immediately set when the first render of `ReactGoogleMaps` occurs. Because of this, when you try to access lat of props.coordinates[0] you get this undefined error.

I recommend either:

- Not rendering ReactGoogleMaps until coords.length > 0
- Check the existence of that first elem before trying to access like below:

```js
    function ReactGoogleMaps(props) {
        return (
            <div style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}>
                { props.coordinates[0] &&
                    <WrappedMap 
                        coordinates={{lat: props.coordinates[0].lat, lng: props.coordinates[0].lng}}
                    />
                }
            </div>
        )
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is child even getting updated props? IMO, the after you use setCoords, the props isn't get updated in child.

First Solution initialize with default values that you're using:

```
 const [coords, setCoords] = useState ([
              {lat: -5.2119899, lng: 119.4461816},
           {lat: -5.209704, lng: 119.44075},
])
```

Second Solution, try UseEffect():

```
function ReactGoogleMaps(props) {
    const [coords, setCords] = useState (props.coordinates)
      useEffect(() => {
         setCords(props.coordinates);
     }, [props]);

    return (
        <div style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}>
            <WrappedMap 
                coordinates={{lat: coords[0].lat, lng: coords[0].lng}}
            />
        </div>
    )
};
```

#### Note: I haven't tested it but hope it works